# Nested foreach php

Tags: php, arrays

```
288
   36
      123
      456
      789
29
   36
      123
      456
      789
295
   36
      123
      456
      789
```

288,29,295 are my first array 36,36,36 are my array of array and 123,456,789 are my another array.

I want to display

```
288
   36
      123
29
   36
      456
295
   36
      789
```

Here is my code

```
$nos = $_POST['nos'];
$nos2 = $_POST['nos2'];
$nos3 = $_POST['nos3'];
    foreach($nos as $nbs)
    {
        echo $nbs."<br>";   
        foreach($nos2 as $nbs2)
        {
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$nbs2."<br>";
            foreach($nos3 as $nbs3)
            {
                echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$nbs3."<br>";

            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

how can i do it using foreach
help me please.

Answer (score 3):

Use for loop instead :

```
    $nos = $_POST['nos'];
    $nos2 = $_POST['nos2'];
    $nos3 = $_POST['nos3'];
    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($nos) ; $i++){
      if(isset($nos[$i])) echo $nos[$i]."<br>";
      if(isset($nos2[$i])) echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$nos2[$i]."<br>";
      if(isset($nos3[$i])) echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$nos3[$i]."<br>";
    }
```

Or foreach like this

```
    $nos = $_POST['nos'];
    $nos2 = $_POST['nos2'];
    $nos3 = $_POST['nos3'];
    foreach($nos as $i => $n){
      echo $n."<br>";
      if(isset($nos2[$i])) echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$nos2[$i]."<br>";
      if(isset($nos3[$i])) echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$nos3[$i]."<br>";
    }
```

**EDIT**

If you haven't numeric key or different index, you can change assignation by array_values http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

```
    $nos = array_values($_POST['nos']);
    $nos2 = array_values($_POST['nos2']);
    $nos3 = array_values($_POST['nos3']);
```

https://eval.in/671937

Comment: its work fine but what happen when key was not 0,1,2(key was different) for array? https://eval.in/671936

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
use counter, so it will display foreach of $nos3(last foreach loop) value as expected output

```
$counts = 0;
foreach($nos as $nbs)
{   
    echo $nbs."<br>";   
    foreach($nos2 as $nbs2)
    {
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$nbs2."<br>";
        $sub_counts = 0;
        foreach($nos3 as $nbs3)
        {
            if($counts == $sub_counts)
            {
                echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$nbs3."<br>";
            }           
            $sub_counts ++;
        }
        break;
    }
    $counts ++;
}
```

i hope it will be helpful.

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/671926)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are just debugging the contents of your nested array and you want to look at it in a human friendly way you could try either:

`print_r($my_nested_array)` - see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

or

`var_dump($my_nested_array)` - see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)